# Firebase in Android: Invalid Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request

Tags: php, android, json, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here's the part of the `PHP` file.

```
// Firebase config
define("FIREBASE_SERVER_KEY", "key");
```

I found that key at the Firebase webpage. That is the server key, not the web `API` key.

When I try to send the push notification, I get the message `Invalid Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request`. So now I went to the `google-services.json` file that I downloaded and pasted to the app, and here it is.

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "109514033229",
    "firebase_url": "https://authentication-d186e.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "authentication-d186e",
    "storage_bucket": "authentication-d186e.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:109514033229:android:9cbb45c552e1d290",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.marshall.authentication"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "109514033229-3vtiahoqpoj5laukd8l3mcbr3gsmofhv.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "current_key"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

Does this error have to do with this `JSON` file? Or what should I do solve this issue?

Comment: I think this error is pertaining to a [MismatchSenderId](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes). Can you try to uninstall and re-install your app before sending a push notification? It's possible that you were using a previous SenderID and the current registration token isn't associated with your current project.

Comment: Well that didn't work.. How should I deal with the `Sender ID`?

Comment: Hmmm. When calling the `getToken()` in your Android app, pass in your Sender ID and `"FCM"` like -- `getToken(2xxxxxxxx, "FCM")`. Then try to send a message.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but can you give me an example code?

Comment: Hey. No worries. When you're calling the [`FirebaseInstanceId.getToken()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken()) (probably in your MainActivity's `onCreate()`, just pass in your Sender ID and the String "FCM" as I mentioned previously. It's pretty much the sample code itself.

Comment: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken("sender_id", "FCM") threw the `IOException`..

Comment: `02-14 19:48:32.744 9553-9553/com.marshall.authentication W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.getToken(Unknown Source)`
`02-14 19:48:32.744 9553-9553/com.marshall.authentication W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getToken(Unknown Source)`

Comment: I doubt that. I checked out the reference (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getToken(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) and it says the first parameter is the String type, not integer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135677/discussion-between-al-and-marshall-s-lee).