# why I can't send push notification from my PHP server to my iOS app?

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am a beginner in PHP development, I want to `make push notification` using firebase cloud messaging to `my iOS App`. if I compose the message through firebase console,  **I can send the notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging console to my client App .**

**but if I compose the message from my own PHP server, I can not get the notification in my client App**. it seems that my backend server can't connect to the `iOS firebase cloud messaging`. am I missing like API key to be written in my PHP code?

I connect the APN and the FCM using APNs Authentication Key, not APNs certificate.

I also have made `push notification` for my android app, and I can send the `notification from Firebase console` and also from my own server to my `client app`.

I get confused with the API in from firebase to my PHP script. what API Access key that I should copy and paste to my PHP script from my Firebase?

```
 define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-SERVER-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
```

I got the response message

> Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to
>   perform request.

here is the full code I use in my PHP script to send the notification to my iOS app.

```
<?php
#API access key from Google API's Console
    define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'YOUR-SERVER-API-ACCESS-KEY-GOES-HERE' );
    $registrationIds = $_GET['id'];
#prep the bundle
     $msg = array
          (
        'body'  => 'Body  Of Notification',
        'title' => 'Title Of Notification',
                'icon'  => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
          );
    $fields = array
            (
                'to'        => $registrationIds,
                'notification'  => $msg
            );


    $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
#Send Reponse To FireBase Server    
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
        curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
#Echo Result Of FireBase Server
echo $result;
```

what went wrong in here? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you saying you can receive a push message on your andriod but not on your iOS deivce when you push a message via your php server? What is the result message?

Comment: Thanks chris, Yes i can send to the android but not to the ios. the response message is : Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.

Comment: You may want to double check your server key details or just simply test it via a curl from your php server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42222672/firebase-in-android-invalid-server-key-delivered-or-sender-is-not-authorized-to